# Why a Swift existential overload is preferred rather and the generic one?

Tags: swift, generics, overloading, existential-type

In the following code snippet, I defined two structs conforming to a common protocol. Then, I defined three overloads for a function: a concrete one, a generic one and an existential one:

```swift
protocol Foo { }

struct Bar: Foo { }
struct Baz: Foo { }

func process(_ data: Bar) { print("Bar") }  // Concrete
func process<D: Foo>(_ data: D) { print("Generic") }  // Generic
func process(_ data: any Foo) { print("Existential") }  // Existential

process(Bar())  // prints "Bar"
process(Baz())  // prints "Existential"
```

Why does for the call to `process(Baz())` the compiler chooses the existential overload while there is a more specific one, i.e. the generic one?

Also, I would have expected the compiler to enforce the programmer to write something like this for it to acknowledge that the instance is being wrapped in the existential type:

```swift
process(Baz() as Foo)  // Explicit conversion to the existential type
```

Is this behavior expected, and is the only solution is to use the `@disfavoredOverload` attribute on the existential overload?

Comment: I think it's better to ask at https://forums.swift.org/

Comment: "Why does for the call to `process(Bar())` the compiler chooses the existential overload" According to you it doesn't. It chooses the concrete.

Comment: This was a typo, I fixed it.